Scooby Doo : Mystery Incorporated episode about a seal or sea lion
(This was a few days ago so I might not remember much)
I was watching TV and I almost missed an episode of Scooby Doo : Mystery Incorporated. So I only got to see the part where the gang was looking for someone while on a submarine and then a seal (or sea lion) came to the submarine they were standing on and showed them a cracked glass bowl.
And then daphine (idk how to spell her name) hugged ted (I think that is his name) because she was sad.
I was wondering if they find who they were looking for in a later episode and I would like to know the episodes name when they find who they were looking for (if they did...)
And idk what that episode was called :( I forgot to check.

I think you're looking for Episode 11 : The Midnight Zone

When the gang realizes that the robots are coming from deep underwater, Daphne recruits two of her babysitting charges, Tom and Tub, and their seal (also named Scooby), to transport the gang in their submarine to the robots' spawning vats, in an area the kids call "The Midnight Zone". Shortly after submerging, the sub is attacked by a group of robots and damaged, and the gang stumble upon an underwater base and attempt to use it to repair the sub, only to discover that the base is the factory where the robots are constructed, run by Professor Pericles. In the end, Pericles escapes leaving the laboratory to self-destruct, killing Cassidy Williams as the gang, Tom and Tub, and Scooby the Seal escape.




